# Delete from multiple table using foreign key is not working

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, sql-delete, multiple-tables

I want to delete a students record on the base on student id. which is primery key in student_tbl and foreign key in all other tables. But I am not getting through; I am getting this error:

> #1109 - Unknown table 'student_tbl' in MULTI DELETE

```
DELETE FROM `student_tbl`,`father`,`sponsor`, `postal`, `report` USING `student_tbl` std 
  INNER JOIN `father` INNER JOIN `sponsor` INNER JOIN `postal` INNER JOIN `report` 
  WHERE std.s_id = 1 AND father.s_id = std.s_id AND sponsor.s_id = std.s_id
  AND postal.s_id = std.s_id AND report.s_id = std.s_id
```

Comment: Have you tried running that query in your SQL browser ?

Comment: yes i get this error   #1109 - Unknown table 'student_tbl' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: do table student_tbl exists ?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this issue by changing the table `student_tbl` name with it's alias name.